# Count Directory Files then Test Numeric values

Tags: batch-file

Using the code below I am able to count the number of files in a directory and call another batch file if the number of files in the directory equals (EQU or ==) say 20
When i use LSS i run into a few problems. The results are problematic and i am getting unexpected results depending on how many files are in the directory or the value of LSS
If for example i have 9 files in my directory and LSS set for say 15 the call command doesn't work.
Is there a way to fix this possible number Vs string issue. I have also tried using "" around the numbers but still no luck. Any help would be appreciated

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET count=0 
for %%o IN (C:\test1\*.*) DO ( 
      echo %%o 
      SET /A count=count + 1 
)

echo %count%

IF %count% LSS 20 call RunAll.bat

ENDLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: `LSS` means _less than_. Run the script from an open `cmd` window and share unexpected vs. desired results.

Comment: @JosefZ I think he knows what `LSS` means seeing as he specifically mentions _for example i have 9 files in my directory and LSS set for say 15 the call command doesn't work_

Comment: Try `IF %count% LSS 20 ECHO call RunAll.bat` just between `echo %count%` and `IF %count% LSS 20 call RunAll.bat`

Answer (score 0):

you `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` but you do not use its functionality. It makes more sense to wrap your `if` in double quotes or square brackets.

Lastly, no need to call `RunAll.bat` just can it without call.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0 
for %%o in (F:\CSV\*) do ( 
      echo %%o
      set /A count=count + 1 
)
echo !count!
if "!count!" LSS "20" RunAll.bat
endlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```